# Show or film where "stranger" is a low-key compliment?

Tags: story-identification

I saw a film or episode of a show last week, where one of the major characters was repeatedly called "stranger" by a minor character. It was sort of implied to be an insult, as the two characters were already acquainted. But eventually another character explains that "stranger" is something of a compliment where they are, because all the helpful specialists they ever encounter aren't local to the community, or something like that.

I believe the explanation started something like: "Don't be offended, 'Stranger' has a different meaning here".

Some of the things I watched recently (i.e., possible candidates): Star Wars Rebels (s3 and s4), Doctor Strange in The Multiverse of Madness, Star Wars Visions (e1 and e2), Obi-Wan Kenobi (all episodes).

Comment: I haven't seen the show, but this sounds like it would fit the setting of *Westworld*.

Comment: @ZeissIkon: good guess, but that's not it.

Comment: You watched it *last week*?

Comment: @user108131 I don't know exactly when, but let's say in the last 30 days. Could have been several years old content, still!